# jQuery slider menu

Tags: jquery

I'm currently designing a website that is supposed to be divided into three main sections. To do that, I'd like to use a big menu like the one on the image below. When the user hovers over one of the three boxes, it should expand to reveal some more information about the section and so on.

I think I've already seen something like this on some website but I can't remember where. Do you think there is any jQuery plugin I could use for this?

[image]

Comment: I'd look into jQuery's animate function.

Comment: You'd want to search for a jQuery accordion plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jquery plugin called **kwicks**

[image]

[Example](http://www.jeremymartin.name/examples/kwicks.php?example=1)

[Source](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery accordion will do exactly what you are looking to do. Link here: [Jquery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this recently.  While I was not able to find a plugin that did exactly what I wanted, it was fairly easy to roll my own using the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  Basically on your mouse over event you will want something like this:

```
var expandedWidth = 300;
var collapsedWidth = 100;
var duration = 400;

$(this).animate({ width: expandedWidth }, duration );
```

and on mouse out something like this:

```
$(this).animate({ width: collapsedWidth }, duration );
```